# Overriding the init() method , Cocos2d-x v2.2

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I can not seem to override the init() method in my class which is subclass of CCLayer. 
I was able to override the create() method. All i need to do is pass an int when i create the layer to the init() method:
here's the create (int n) method

```
CCLayer* Stage::create(int n)
{
    CCLayer *pRet = new CCLayer();
    if (pRet && pRet->init(n))
    {
        pRet->autorelease();
        return pRet;
    }
    else
    {
        CC_SAFE_DELETE(pRet);
        return NULL;
    }
}

bool DuneStage::init(int ss)
{
   // this code should execute 
}
```

In the .h file:

```
virtual bool init(int n);  
static CCLayer* create(int z);
```

also do I need to override this method in the CCLayer.cpp file?

```
bool CCLayer::init()
{
    bool bRet = false;
    do 
    {        
        CCDirector * pDirector;
        CC_BREAK_IF(!(pDirector = CCDirector::sharedDirector()));
        this->setContentSize(pDirector->getWinSize());
        m_bTouchEnabled = false;
        m_bAccelerometerEnabled = false;
        // success
        bRet = true;
    } while(0);
    return bRet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overridden method signature must be of parent class method `virtual bool init()`

If you want to send arguments then you can declare them as member variable in your CCLayer subclass and then assign them before calling `init` method in `create` method.

```
CCLayer* Stage::create(int n)
{
   CCLayer *pRet = new CCLayer();
   pRet->n = n
   ...........
   ...........
}

Stage* Stage::create(int n)
{
   Stage* pRet = new Stage();
   pRet->n = n
   ...........
   ...........
}
```

Comment: but the variable n is in Stage not CCLayer